# Docking PyQt Windows from separate processes

Tags: python, pyqt, dock, multiprocess, gil

I am designing a PyQt based application which has some components which do some heavy lifting in the GUI thread (live plotting some relatively large data-sets).

My experience is that other parts of my GUI can get somewhat unresponsive while this is happening - also I want to run multiple threads and avoid running into the old GIL problem.

To work around both of these issues, I want to run various parts of my application as separate processes (either using multiprocessing module or launching parallel python instances which communicate over sockets).

I am wondering if there is any way I can get the windows from the other processes to dock in my main window.

Minimal example by request:

**sub_proc_a.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

sub_process_window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
sub_process_window.setWindowTitle("Dock Me!")
sub_process_window.show()

app.exec_()
```

**master_proc.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from subprocess import Popen

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
main_window.setWindowTitle("Main window")
main_window.show()

sub_proc_a = Popen("python sub_proc_a.py")

# HOW DO I GET HANDLES TO THE WINDOWS OPENED by sub_proc_a such that I can dock them?

app.exec_()
```

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Answer (score 0):

After working on this issue for weeks, I have found what I'm looking for:

This document describes embedding other windows in Qt:
https://gist.github.com/torarnv/c5dfe2d2bc0c089910ce

My other question here shows most of what's needed to dock the widget by hwnd value:
[Embedding native windows inside QDockWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381894/embedding-native-windows-inside-qdockwidget)